# Advice: "Stained Glass Optimization and Coloring"

Tags: optimization, soft-question, linear-programming, math-software, art

I hope everything is going well for everyone reading this at the moment. I am hoping someone here could offer some guidance and advice for a problem I am looking into.

**Problem**

I would like to be able to take a picture and turn the relevant regions (e.g. face / body / not the background) of the picture (or maybe all of it) into polygons (just triangles would suffice) and then color the polygons forming the object of the picture to satisfy some constraints (e.g. color gradients in the original picture are preserved or no two of the same colors out of a set of colors are touching each other).

I believe such an approach would be possible with generative adversarial networks, but I would like to take a linear optimization approach here and not a machine learning one.

I have been thinking about using [Delaunay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) after a friend recommended it to me. At the end is an example image of this (source: Wikipedia).

For delimiting the object of the image, I am thinking about using a [Traveling Sales Person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) (TSP) approach but am unsure of what exactly to do.

So, does anyone here have any recommendations for (1) optimizing the edges of the object of the image so that the border around it is complete, (2) filling the space in the border with polygon shapes satisfying some constraints, (3) coloring these polygons to satisfy some constraints, (4) the software (I am thinking a mixture of Gurobi and Python) I should use to complete this task?

Thank you for your time.

[image: Example of Delanunay Triangulation]

Comment: You could use a clustering algorithm such as spectral clustering to partition an image into superpixels. The superpixels will not be polygons, however. You can see an example of what superpixels look like here: https://medium.com/@darshita1405/superpixels-and-slic-6b2d8a6e4f08#:~:text=A%20superpixel%20can%20be%20defined,etc%20because%20of%20the%20following-

Comment: @littleO That's pretty interesting! I hadn't heard of such a thing (superpixels) before; it seems quite cool but a little off from what I am looking for. Thank you for helping me learn nonetheless!

Comment: The TSP has nothing to do with what you are asking. It seems that you like to randomly pick buzzwords. :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am not randomly choosing buzzwords. My suggestions for how to do this (since I really do not know the best methods) are to use Delaunay Triangulation, or a combination of this and TSP. I would first use weighted Voronoi stippling to get the dots of the svg / png image, and then I might use the border generated by TSP to defined the boundary for the dots for the Delaunay Triangulation. So, my thought is that TSP could be used here to defined a more starting image to then employ Delaunay Triangulation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do you have any other suggestions, given that you profess to have knowledge of optimization that is beyond me? Are you familiar with any algorithms for something that can optimize for a stained glass pattern? Also, the techniques I wrote about in this post were certainly not picked randomly - they were the ones that I thought might be most useful for my problem. I do not know how they can be perceived as being random. Imagine using TSP on an image (e.g. https://www2.oberlin.edu/math/faculty/bosch/tspart-page.html) and then using Delaunay Triangulation in the regions between borders

Comment: A starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation